# how to I remove the "" from a String so that I can convert a string with numbers to integer?

Tags: java

I am trying to remove all letters and print the numbers, and then their numbers in java.
My data sets :
6
Stanley worked for a company in a big building as emplyee number 427.
Employee 427's job was simple: he sat in room 427 and worked at his desk.
Stanley was happy.
That coffee will cost you $4.20.
Linux L1 3.5.0-45-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 2 21:58:52 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2,014 

desired result: 
427
427
427 427
854
-
0
4 20
24
3 5 0 45 68 2 21 58 52 86 64
404
2 14
16

My code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("txt.txt"));
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    String x = sc.next();

    for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
        int sum =0;
        String[] word = sc.nextLine().trim().split("\\D+");
        List<String> item = Arrays.asList(word);
        if(word.length!=0){

            for(int j = 0; j<word.length; j++){


           if(j==0){

               int num = Integer.parseInt(word[j].trim());
               out.print(word[j]);
               sum+=num;

           }
           else{

               int num = Integer.parseInt(word[j].trim());
               out.print(word[j]+" ");
               sum+=num;


           }

        }
        out.println(sum);
        out.println();

        }
        else{
            out.println("-");
            out.println("0");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48688582/edit) your question to show the output you expect, and the output you're actually getting - in other words, give a [mcve].

Comment: "Numbers of numbers in java"? What does that mean?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I guess he meant "the count" of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that matches all non-digits: `\D`. So if you really want to discard all other characters and only leave decimal digits, use

```
String digitsOnly = myString.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Beware this may swallow decimal point and any separators between multiple digits if possible.